# The unknown encoded in emf->EMR_EXTTEXTOUTW->EmrText->OutputString

Tags: c#, unicode, spl

I extracted `EMR_EXTTEXTOUTW` elements from an emf file,then extracted  EmrText elements from `EMR_EXTTEXTOUTW` elements,then extracted  OutputString elements from EmrText elements.according to definition,OutputString's encoded is 16-bit `Unicode UTF16-LE` characters.

But some OutputStrings extracted from emf couldn't encode by Unicode UTF16-LE

compare to pictures by emf,I found some comparisons to this unknown

> encoded ,"13 00" ->"0","14 00"->"1",but unicode "0"is"30 00","1"is"31
>   00"

what is the unknown encode?

Comment: eg:
EmrText

A8 00 00 00 38 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 4C 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 50 00 00 00 17 00 13 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

and it's OutputString  is "40" ,but it's code is "17 00 13 00" ,Is it unicode ?

Comment: The structure of EmrText was defined in here

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230576.aspx

Comment: In most cases,I get the correct String successfully and it's code is UTF-16 completely.

But in some cases,It's code is not Unicode or ASCII,just an unknown encode.It is strange that window system

 can discriminate the unknown encode when i open a emf file as a picture.

you can see the complete EMR_EXTTEXTOUTW :

54 00 00 00 58 00 00 00 A8 00 00 00 1E 00 00 00 C5 00 00 00 3D 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 48 41 22 2B 48 41 A8 00 00 00 38 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 4C 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 50 00 00 00 17 00 13 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Comment: I know why.It's not unicode but indexes of the character glyphs.